# Facebook user ID may change after upgrade facebbok app version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app version 1.0, now this app returns the global ID, but after April 30 will automatically upgrade to 2.0.

I want to know, if after April 30, then facebook user authorized my facebook app 1.0 returns the global ID (as above) or app scope ID ?

Comment: You will always get the id you got the first time they logged into your app. So if they logged in using v1.0 and you got the global id you will always get that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Users that log into your application will always have the same user ID, even after v2.x is enforced on April 30th, 2015. This means that for older apps that were created before **April 30th, 2014**, if a user logged in and is associated to a global ID, they will forever be associated with their global ID.

This is described in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) under the sub-section "Changes from v1.0 to v2.0". Specifically, it states that "for users that have previously logged into your app, the user ID will not change."